# How do I monitor COM ports in an ASP.NET application

Tags: asp.net, serial-port

An application we're developing requires the user to scan barcodes at various points in a factory. The application will only display the results of the scans to e.g. foremen or admin staff.

Basically, I'd need my web application to listen to incoming COM messages on certain COM ports independent from HTTP requests and responses.

Is this possible? I'd like to implement it without having to install a windows service if I can.

I do have a class which pushes a new "watcher" object onto a stack for each known scanner connected to a unique COM port. Will it work if I create a static reference to the collection of watchers on application start?

Comment: Don't. It's a bad idea. Instead, make a windows service that handles the COM communication, and communicates with the ASP.NET application in turn. Why are you trying to avoid using a windows service?

Comment: A self-contained application is much easier to deploy and will avoid battling the client's IT department over permissions and potential security concerns.

Comment: So you're saying it's easier to get approval for elevated permissions for your whole web application than just for a tiny service handling just one thing? Ouch.

Comment: As far as I know it is imposible to do it. Your webapp is running on the server. Do you want to connect all the Scanners' COM ports to the server from all points of the factory?? I suggest  you to take a look at the SignalR library. It might be helpful.